# How to save a variable before serving a file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express, progressive-web-apps

given the following code:

```
 const https = require('https');
 const fs = require('fs');
 var path = require('path');
 const express = require('express');
 const app = express();
 const router = express.Router();
 const pool = require('./mysqldb.js');
 const pathView = __dirname + "/views/";
 const IMGPath = "/public";
 var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
 const listenPort = 8010;
 var id = null ;

 router.get('/details/:id', async function (req, res, next) {
 id = req.params.id;
 if ( typeof req.params.id === "number"){id = parseInt(id);}
 res.render('details.ejs' );
 });
```

The main goal is to save that req.params.id(the id from the url) in the id variable before serving the details.ejs file.I tried to remove the async but didn't work.Can you help me please?

Comment: So details.ejs gives you information including the `id`, and in that file `id` is not correct?

Comment: You are not using the `id`. Why do you need it? Do you use it somewhere else?

Comment: The details.ejs gives me the id from the url and yes it is correct.I'm using the id on the details.ejs page when I call using axios an url like /getData from a database which is using this id to query and the problem is the router.get is asynchronous and I query the database with id = null.

Comment: All I need is to save first the id and then response with the details.ejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `await` keywords inside your `async` function like so:

```
router.get('/details/:id', async function (req, res, next) {
    await (() => { id = req.params.id; })(); // Will run first
    await (() => { res.send(id); })(); // Will run second
})
```

`res.send(id)` or `res.render('details.ejs')` ( in your case ) will run after the id is retrieved

Comment: No problem, if my answer did it please do accept it, otherwise try to reproduce the problem and let us know if its still a problem. you might need to experiment with the value of `id` in various changes to hunt down the problem

Comment: The `await`s and inner functions should be unneeded. `res.send(req.params.id);` should just work by itself.

Comment: I provided a way to use `await` by using self-declared functions since the function is `async` and `await` can't be used like so: `await id = req.params.id` since I assumed that's what the OP wanted. Indeed it would work the same way by just returning directly the parameter in the send function ( assuming that's all the OP wanted, which probably is not )

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine for me. Below, I launch this server, then I go to `http://localhost:3050/123` and suddenly I'm console.logging '123' over and over again, and the correct text displays on the screen.

So... idk what else if going on for you, but it might help if you try your best to distill your code down to the simplest possible iteration to try to debug. Just try to replicate it elsewhere. You might find one of your additional modules is causing an issue.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const port = 3050;

let id = null; 

app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    return res.send('Hello World!')
}); 

app.get('/details/:id', (req, res) => {
    if (req.params.id){
        id = req.params.id;
    }

    // 'id' will appear in browser
    return res.send(`See details for id: ${id}`); 
}); 

// console logs of 'id'
setInterval(() => { console.log(`id is currently ${id}`); }, 1000);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

I don't think `async/await` will have any effect on this specific issue. I doubt they're related.

Comment: To be honest,I don't know why I have this problem.I had the same nodejs structure all this time,it was working till at some point.Maybe because on the /details webpage I'm loading pretty much data using axios....Anyway,thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me,

```
router.get('/details/:id', async function (req, res, next) {
  id = typeof req.params.id === 'number' ? parseInt(id) : req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  res.send('details.ejs' );
});
```